# Native PowerShell ForEach loop to delete files in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, foreach

I'm trying to put together a simple PowerShell script to delete files from an AWS S3 bucket. I'm unable to split the filename correctly from items in the loop.

How is the filename correctly selected?

**Example record names:**

```
2021-06-07 16:08:15    1876349 20210502210533.csv
2021-06-07 16:44:53    1858461 210502210533.csv
2021-06-07 16:18:39  276597534 20210424203918.csv
```

**Example script:**

`$all_files=aws s3 ls s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/ --profile dev`

```
foreach($file in $all_files)
{
    aws s3 rm s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/$file.Split(' ')[6] --profile dev
}
```

**Results:**

```
delete: s3 ls s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2021-06-07 16:44:53    1858461 20210502210533.csv.Split
delete: s3 ls s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2021-06-07 16:18:39  276597534 20210424203918.csv.Split
delete: s3 ls s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2021-06-07 15:50:41  276597534 20210424204122.csv.Split
```

Notice how the entire record is present (no split occurring). How do I reliably split this?

**EDIT 1:**

```
$all_files=aws s3 ls s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/ --profile dev
```

```
PS C:\Users\me> $all_files
2021-06-08 02:50:37 4637885036 20210425202931.csv
2021-06-08 02:53:23 4753217891 20210426204043P.csv
2021-06-08 02:59:10 4838159267 20210426204346.csv
2021-06-08 02:58:07 4871146830 20210426204407.csv
2021-06-08 03:00:24 4641073848 20210427203146.csv
2021-06-08 02:52:29 4633473584 20210427203836.csv
2021-06-08 02:57:55 4633473584 20210427204657.csv
2021-06-08 02:56:25 4633473584 20210428203618.csv
2021-06-08 02:53:30 4633473584 20210429204253.csv
```

```
PS C:\Users\me> ForEach($file in $all_files){$command = 'aws s3 rm s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/' + $file.Split(' ')[-1] + ' --profile dev' & $command}

At line:1 char:177
+ ... folder3/folder4/' + $file.Split(' ')[-1] + ' --profile vis_dev' & $comman ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token '&' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

If I leave the `& $command` off the end, then run `Invoke-Expression $command` as a second expression, the last file is deleted.

How is the `& $command` run as part of the loop?

Comment: Can you provide a few of the elements from `$all_files`.  The split should be no problem, but we'd need the actual strings.  If you look at the current results split is being appended to the string so something is up with how this is quoted or whatnot.

Comment: Sure thing. Added.

Comment: Curious why you're doing this with the `aws` command-line tool and not the native Powershell functions for AWS. You should be able to [get a list of all object in the bucket](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3Object.html), then pass that whole list to [Remove-S3Object](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/powershell/latest/reference/items/Remove-S3Object.html), without a loop.

Comment: You could use `aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query 'Contents[].Key' --output text | tr '\t' '\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$All_Files = @(
    '2021-06-07 16:08:15    1876349 20210502210533.csv'
    '2021-06-07 16:44:53    1858461 210502210533.csv'
    '2021-06-07 16:18:39  276597534 20210424203918.csv'
)

ForEach($File in $All_Files)
{
    'aws s3 rm s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/' + $file.Split(' ')[-1]
}
```

If you just use normal string concatenation this should output what you're looking for.

If you are going to split using the string `.Split()` method you're reliance on the index `[6]` is problematic. `[-1]` will simply give you the last element in the resulting array.

If you are looking to execute the resulting string as a command I would assign it to a variable and include other required arguments, then use the call operator (`&`) to execute it.

```
ForEach($File in $All_Files)
{
    $command = 'aws s3 rm s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/' + $file.Split(' ')[-1] + ' --profile dev'
    & $command
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The `--profile dev` flag is not able to be passed using the above syntax. Error: `At line:1 char:145
+ ... r2/folder3/folder4/' + $file.Split(' ')[-1] --profile dev ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'profile' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`. How is this flag passed to the command?

Comment: That is only to address the split issue and concatenation. I don't know AWS , but if you amend to also concatenate `--profile dev` preferably while assigning to a variable like `$command` then use the `&` operator to call it.  I'll amend the answer as such.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't seem to like the last `& $command`. Results in: `Unexpected token '&' in expression or statement'.

Comment: That is weird because it's complaining about the "&" not the command itself.  Try typing the ampersand manually, no copy/paste...

Comment: Hm. Yeah, I typed in the entire command. No go when the `& $command` is inline.

Comment: Ended up just using the `aws cli` to run `aws s3 rm s3://bucket.host.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/ --recursive --profile vis_dev`. Worked like a charm!